# Using Json in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, visual-studio-2010

Attempting to use [JSON serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839026/working-with-json-in-c-sharp-net-3-5) assembly reference for C#.Net project.

Apparently this has to be separately downloaded and installed through the management of NuGet packages. This is detailed in other answers is StackOverflow. However, much to my surprise, this does not seem to have resolved the problem.

[image: Manage NuGet packages]

.

[image: JSON.Net]

The [System.Runtime.Serialization.Json](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.aspx) reference also does not appear in the Framework Assemblies. There does not seem to be any mention of JSON in the extensions either.

[image: .Net Framework Assemblies]

Comment: Could you give constructive criticism instead of downvoting and voting to close. You (anonymously) have voted to close due to the question "being unclear". If you find it unclear you can comment below the question. Thank you.

Comment: I've not downvoted but asking, didn't you find assemblies in your bin folder after installing nu-get package?

Comment: What does the question you're linking to have to do with this question? Also, why am I seeing so many people handling their json like this now instead of using json.NET? System.Runtime.Serialization.Json is just complete shit in comparision to json.NET. It has less functionality and makes you write ugly code with annotations like `[CollectionDataContract]` with json.NET it's just `List<Person> people = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Person>>(myJsonAsAString);` and in one line it does the nonsense you're creating a useless class to do.

Comment: @NileshThakkar : browsing through Windows Explorer I can see Newtonsoft.Json.dll is sitting in the project folder's bin subfolder. Is this what you're talking about>

Comment: @Duncan no. If you want to use it you need `using Newtonsoft.Json;`, they're different assemblies and you should just use json.net cause as I was just saying it's a lot better (newtonsoft.json is json.net in case you're not aware).

Comment: @evanmcdonnal : I think there might've been a typo in your comment (newtonsoft.json is not json.net)?

I have no real preference between json.net and newtonsoft.json: having used neither before. But I found documentation that gave some sort of detail as how to go about using the latter, but didn't for the former so that was a deciding factor.

As neither is natively incorporated into ASP.Net (for reasons best known by Microsoft) the same hurdle of actually getting them to work in a project must be overcome.

Comment: json.NET refers to the json parsing tools developed by James Newton King. `Newtonsoft.Json` is one of the assemblies/namespaces within json.NET. I put that comment in parens because I was interchanging the names and wanted to make it clear that I was referring to the same thing throughout my comments. Also, as I said in the first comment that `[CollectionDataContractAttribute]` annotation nonsense is required for `Serialization.Json`, it's not used by other libraries and will cause compilation errors if you don't use that library. In my first comment I have the line of code you should use.

Comment: @Duncan use json.NET, the simplest example is here http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx they have everything you need in the docs there. If you're stuck on something ask specific questions about it on SO. I'm sure there are plenty of users (myself included) who have sufficient json.NET experience that will answer your questions. There are no annotations required. json.NET uses reflection, just define the objects you have in json (or want in json) like you would any others and then call serialize/deserialize on them. Everything works as you'd probably expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can click show all files icon in solution explorer, and check out the bin folder of your solution, Newtonsoft.Json.dll file must be there.

You can also open packet manager and can view installed packages for given solution.

You just need to add below statement in your .cs files, and you're ready to go.

```
 using Newtonsoft.Json;
```